# How to 301 redirect site alias domain to a subdomain on the same hosting?

Tags: php, wordpress, htaccess, redirects, cpanel

We have the following problem in Cpanel / htaccess file when trying to 301 redirect `example.hu` (alias) pages to `example.com` (subdomain) pages:

Cpanel `example.hu` to `example.com` redirection is working, but any additional 301 page redirects won't work and redirect the (alias) `example.hu/hu/page` to the main domain's home page (`anotherdomain.example`).

Main domain & the alias domain (alias domain is also added as subdomains to Cpanel) share the same root directory, could this be the problem? Should I remove the alias domain and changes to Cpanel 301 redirect / `.htaccess` file modification will start to work?

Comment: Assuming cPanel has simply updated the `.htaccess` file then you need to edit your question to include the contents of your complete `.htaccess` file.